# why domain name will be removed automatically from my django.setting

Tags: django, dns, bitnami

i use bitnami-django-stack to set up website on google-cloud-platform and have bought a domain name from namesilo. But i can't link domain name to my site.
i have added ip and domain name in ALLOWED_HOSTS:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=[ip, domain name, www.domain name]
LOGIN_URL = '/account/login/'
```

i can login with ip/account/login
But if i use domain name/account/login
"Invalid HTTP_HOST header" occurs
and debug setting shows ALLOWED_HOSTS=[ip]

why? domain name and www.domain name disappear ?
Please help me fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the solution in the following post works for you?

https://community.bitnami.com/t/why-allowed-hosts-was-deleted-by-django/61521/5#post_5